# Kubuntu 15.04 Freezes On Startup

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 15.04

I have a fresh installation of Kubuntu 15.04. Every few boots, it freezes completely during startup with the kubuntu logo showing before the login screen shows, ctrl+alt+F# / ctrl+alt+del do nothing. When that happens, a hard restart helps and it boots normally after that. How can I find out what's wrong?

Comment: At what point exactly does it hang? Is it past the login screen or still in the splash screen before X is started? Please [edit] your question to include these details and try to be as specific as you can.

Comment: Does numlock light still respond to num lock button presses? (and caps lock). If not, it's a probably a full kernel hang. You can try to change your kernel parameters to be more verbose during startup. Remove `quiet splash` from `/etc/default/grub` settings and run `sudo update-grub`, or remove it manually during boot every time in Grub itself. (Lots of instructions everywhere, too long for this comment). Then when it hangs, you have at least the last line. E.g. Network connection fails to start or a service that's blocking the X start. etc.

Comment: Unfortunately my laptop doesn't have a numlock light, so I can't tell... Anyway, I've followed your suggestion and am now waiting for my computer to freeze again. Funnily enough it stopped happening...